# Firebase Passwordless Email Authentication Error in Expo App

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am setting up passwordless Auth in my Expo app using the Firebase SDK. I've gotten to the point where emails are being sent to the user's desired address with a redirect link back to the app. When the user clicks the link, they are indeed redirected but they are not being authenticated. I am receiving a generic error in the console :

```
ERROR: [Error: An internal error has occurred.]
```

But I know that my credentials are passing through properly as I have logged them out when the function runs:

```
isSignInWithEmailLink:true, url: exp://10.0.0.27:19000?apiKey=AIzaSyAmpd5DdsjOb-MNfVH3MgF1Gn2nT3TBcnY&oobCode=7FJTfBjM28gkn6GfBSAdgAk7wOegg9k4D5poVcylhSYAAAF8BO5gHQ&mode=signIn&lang=en
```

I am calling useEffect on this function:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  signInWithEmailLink();
}, []);
```

Send Link To Email (WORKING)

```js
const sendSignInLinkToEmail = (email) => {
  return auth
    .sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, {
      handleCodeInApp: true,
      url: proxyUrl,
    })
    .then(() => {
      return true;
    });
};
```

User clicks on a link from the email to redirect to the app to Authenticate (NOT WORKING)

```js
const signInWithEmailLink = async () => {
  const url = await Linking.getInitialURL();
  if (url) {
    handleUrl(url);
  }

  Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
    handleUrl(url);
  });
};
```

(RETURNING ERROR)

```js
const handleUrl = async (url) => {
  const isSignInWithEmailLink = auth.isSignInWithEmailLink(url);
  console.log('isSignInWithEmailLink: ', isSignInWithEmailLink, 'url', url);

  if (isSignInWithEmailLink) {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailLink(email, url);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR:', error);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I am trying to do the same

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you enabled email sign in in your firebase console?
2. Are you storing the email in localStorage? It looks undefined in your logic.
3. Your listener should be in the `useEffect` hook.

I've code my code working looking like this:

```
const handleGetInitialURL = async () => {
  const url = await Linking.getInitialURL()
  if (url) {
    handleSignInUrl(url)
  }
}

const handleDeepLink = (event: Linking.EventType) => {
  handleSignInUrl(event.url)
}

useEffect(() => {
  handleGetInitialURL()
  Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink)
  return () => {
    Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleDeepLink)
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: Thanks Shanks! This is exactly what I needed. For those who need more infos, here is a [youtube tutorial I found very helpful](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wcx67t1jdc) (and [part 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fVNt1KjkEk)).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `onAuthStateChanged` within `useEffect` rather than try and log the user in at that point in time. `useEffect` is used when you need your page to re-render based on changes.

For example:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // onAuthStateChanged returns an unsubscriber
    const unsubscribeAuth = auth.onAuthStateChanged(async authenticatedUser => {
      try {
        await (authenticatedUser ? setUser(authenticatedUser) : setUser(null));
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });

    // unsubscribe auth listener on unmount
    return unsubscribeAuth;
  }, []);
```

You should invoke the user sign in method through other means such as a button to sign in, or validate user credentials at some other point within your app.

custom function:

```js
  const onLogin = async () => {
    try {
      if (email !== '' && password !== '') {
        await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setLoginError(error.message);
    }
  };
```

Source: https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-integrate-firebase-authentication-with-an-expo-app

Comment: Thank you I already have this

Comment: authentication is an async process, you cannot have an async process in your `useEffect` - you are invoking the login from the `useEffect` which is not what it was designed for, this can also cause the element to fail to login rather than re-instantiate the existing user from auth's `refresh_token`